# "all they need _is_ some words" or "all they need _are_ some words"

Tags: grammatical-number

Which one is the correct form?

- "all they need *is* some words"
- "all they need *are* some words"

Comment: Both can often be acceptable, but probably more often the singular is preferable. E.g. *"All they need is some words from you."* Copular clauses of this type are not so easy to explain by a simple "rule". If you're interested in understanding this type of construction, then some related topics are copular clauses and cleft constructions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"Some words" is a plural object in this sentence, so it will be "all they need are some words". If it was "a word", it would be "all they need is a word".

Comment: But if you add a collective noun, it becomes singular again, e.g. _all they need is a bunch of words._

Answer (score 7):

Both forms are perfectly fine English. I disagree with the accepted answer by Ronan, in which it is claimed that only the plural form is acceptable.

To begin with, here are examples from published literature where the author used the singular verb *is* despite the fact that complement (in boldface; *some words* in your examples) is in the plural.

*All we need is **examples from ordinary life.*** ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=zhiFBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT199&dq=%22All%20we%20need%20is%20examples%20from%20ordinary%20life%22&pg=PT199#v=onepage&q=%22All%20we%20need%20is%20examples%20from%20ordinary%20life%22&f=false))
*All we need is **other words that mean the same.*** ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=5fcTDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA211&dq=%22All%20we%20need%20is%20other%20words%20that%20mean%20the%20same%22&pg=PA211#v=onepage&q=%22All%20we%20need%20is%20other%20words%20that%20mean%20the%20same%22&f=false))
*All we need is **fewer pounds.*** ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=V5gUkvg5UKoC&lpg=PA14&dq=%22All%20we%20need%20is%20fewer%20pounds%22&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=%22All%20we%20need%20is%20fewer%20pounds%22&f=false))

The plural form is, of course, also found in published literature:

*All we need are **a few symbols here and there.*** ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=LN6YtXhMhiMC&lpg=PA231&dq=%22%20all%20we%20need%20are%20a%20few%20symbols%20here%20and%20there%22&pg=PA231#v=onepage&q=%22%20all%20we%20need%20are%20a%20few%20symbols%20here%20and%20there%22&f=false))
*All we need are **words like 'reason' and 'evidence'.*** ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=CRrVBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT40&dq=%22All%20we%20need%20are%20words%20like%20'reason'%20and%20'evidence'%22&pg=PT40#v=onepage&q=%22All%20we%20need%20are%20words%20like%20'reason'%20and%20'evidence'%22&f=false))
*All we need are **the numbers.*** ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=A1qFY8ZOEcgC&lpg=PA47&dq=%22All%20we%20need%20are%20the%20numbers.%22&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q=%22All%20we%20need%20are%20the%20numbers.%22&f=false))

Another consideration is that, as pointed out in [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) (p. 1423), the construction in question is closely related to the **pseudo-cleft** construction, namely, to

*What they need is/are some words.*

But in pseudo-clefts, both singular and plural are acceptable ([ComGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582517346), p. 767):

> Pseudo-cleft constructions with a fronted object *what* may have a
>   plural subject complement (cf10.34):
>
> *What we need most **is** books.*
>
> But *what* is ambivalent in number, often interpreted as equivalent to
>   either 'the thing that' or 'the things that', so that we also find a
>   plural verb in concord with the subject *what*-clause:
>
> *What we need most **are** books.*

Comment: +1 A lot of work for an old post, but glad there's a good answer here now!!!