# Which of these sentences is correct? Is or Are?? simple... but I've confused myself

Tags: grammar, punctuation

All I watch is crime documentaries.
All I watch are crime documentaries.

I mean, I know "is" refers to one and "are" is for multiple, but does the "All I watch" at the start mean "is" makes more sense, seeing as that's what comes first. I think it would make more sense using "are" if you said: "Crime documentaries are all that I watch". I know you could rephrase the sentence in question, but for the two I have mentioned, which one is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["All I need (is/are) cigarettes and alcohol": which one is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167240/all-i-need-is-are-cigarettes-and-alcohol-which-one-is-correct) and [All they need is some words or all they need are some words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153971/all-they-need-is-some-words-or-all-they-need-are-some-words).

Comment: Related: [“When all you hear is fear and lies”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74072)

Answer (score 0):

“All I watch are crime documentaries,” is correct.

When used with a countable noun, “all” is plural and requires the use of the plural verb for subject-verb agreement.

When used with an uncountable noun, “all” is singular.

The word, “documentaries,” is countable, as opposed to, “all of the dirt is in a pile,” for example, which is singular.