# Singular/Plural forms for is/are

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

```
All that is needed are angle brackets.

All that are needed is angle brackets.
```

For some reason the first sounds better to my ears. Any help on why (or how I am wrong) is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["all they need _is_ some words" or "all they need _are_ some words"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153971/all-they-need-is-some-words-or-all-they-need-are-some-words)

Comment: Be consistent!!

Comment: ... ie consider 'All that is needed is ...' etc. To be fair, there are plenty of respectable-looking hits on a Google search for all 4 possibilities (including "all that **is** needed **is** two").

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of correctness there is an apparent disagreement.

All (that **is** needed) **are** angle brackets. (discordance=disagreement)

All (that **are** needed) **is** angle brackets. (discordance=disagreement)

※ "All" can be used as singular or plural. It depends on how it is used with other words.

**singular**

All is lost.

All is calm tonight.
All is still.
All is OK.

That's all .

All 's well that ends well. (=All that **ends** well **is** well : agreement)

[together with fused/relative clause]

All I want is money.(All that I want)

All is not gold that glitters.(=All that glitters is not gold)

All we can do is to wait for him.(All that we can do)

All of the milk is spilt.

All I want is peace and quiet.

All that's fair must fade.(All that **is** fair)

All that is ancient is beautiful.

**plural**

All were happy. (Everybody was happy:informal)

All are agreed.

All are welcome.

We all have to go. = All of us have to go. = We all of us have to go.

Now your question.

All that is needed is angle brackets.
All that are needed are angle brackets.

My answer
When "all" is used in front of a sentence as a pronoun, as things(not people), and as an antecedent, "singular" is better.

I would write like this : All that is needed is a pair of bracket.(if you don't like bracket**s**)

Comment: Hello, Brandon. Don't you agree that the most upvoted answer at the possible duplicate shows very thorough research?

Comment: Hi, Edwin. Yeah, I appreciate the research and data answered here. But language is not a science and it changes continuously, so focusing on  the easy way to make the questioner understand what they want is also important.

Comment: 'Anyone, anywhere can initiate cardiac resuscitative procedures ... all that is needed are two hands' appears in a scientific article of obvious pedigree [[Relias Media](https://www.reliasmedia.com/articles/66805-cardiac-resuscitation)] (and quoted in a website dealing with improving writing style). There are lots of examples of 'All that is needed are'. Saying that this is not 'better' needs supporting evidence on ELU. ELU's aim is accuracy / fidelity / transparency. Yes it is.

Comment: @Edwin, Thanks for your advice. Meanwhile, there is no absolute rules in language. That's why I used "better" and suggested "a pair of"(in case of "is"). If there are may A, B, C, D,,,,,Z, it will look strange to use "is". From my experience, people tend to use more "singular" and this is optional according to the context.

Comment: "All that glisters is not gold" - William Shakespeare